# Once grammar is complete, what's the best way to walk an ANTLR v4 tree?

Tags: coldfusion, antlr, antlr4

**Goal**

I'm working on a project to create a Varscoper for Coldfusion CFscript. Basically, this means checking through source code files to ensure that developers have properly `var`'d their variables.

After a couple of days of working with ANTLR V4 I have a grammar which generates a very nice parse tree in the GUI view. Now, using that tree I need a way to crawl up and down the nodes programmatically looking for variable declarations and ensure that if they are inside functions they have the proper scoping. If possible I would rather NOT do this in the grammar file as that would require mixing the definition of the language with this specific task.

**What I've tried**

My latest attempt was using the `ParserRuleContext` and attempting to go through it's `children` via `getPayload()`. After checking the class of `getPayLoad()` I would either have a `ParserRuleContext` object or a `Token` object. Unfortunately, using that I was never able to find a way to get the actual rule type for a specific node, only it's containing text. The rule type for each node is neccessary because it matters whether that text node is an ignored right-hand expression, a variable assignment or a function declaration.

**Questions**

1. I am very new to ANTLR, is this even the right approach, or is there a better way to traverse the tree?

Here's my sample java code:

Cfscript.java

```
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.Trees;

public class Cfscript {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRFileStream(args[0]);
        CfscriptLexer lexer = new CfscriptLexer(input);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        CfscriptParser parser = new CfscriptParser(tokens);
        parser.setBuildParseTree(true);
        ParserRuleContext tree = parser.component();
        tree.inspect(parser); // show in gui
        /*
            Recursively go though tree finding function declarations and ensuring all variableDeclarations are varred
            but how?
        */
    }
}
```

Cfscript.g4

```
grammar Cfscript;

component
    : 'component' keyValue* '{' componentBody '}'
    ;

componentBody
    : (componentElement)*
    ;

componentElement
    : statement
    | functionDeclaration
    ;

functionDeclaration
    : Identifier? Identifier? 'function' Identifier argumentsDefinition '{' functionBody '}'
    ;

argumentsDefinition
    : '(' argumentDefinition (',' argumentDefinition)* ')'
    | '()'
    ;

argumentDefinition
    : Identifier? Identifier? argumentName ('=' expression)?
    ; 

argumentName
    : Identifier
    ;

functionBody
    : (statement)*
    ;

statement
    : variableStatement
    | nonVarVariableStatement
    | expressionStatement
    ;

variableStatement
    : 'var' variableName '=' expression ';'
    ;

nonVarVariableStatement
    : variableName '=' expression ';'
    ;

expressionStatement
    : expression ';'
    ;

expression
    : assignmentExpression
    | arrayLiteral
    | objectLiteral
    | StringLiteral
    | incrementExpression
    | decrementExpression
    | 'true' 
    | 'false'
    | Identifier
    ;

incrementExpression
    : variableName '++'
    ;

decrementExpression
    : variableName '--'
    ;

assignmentExpression
    : Identifier (assignmentExpressionSuffix)*
    | assignmentExpression (('+'|'-'|'/'|'*') assignmentExpression)+
    ;

assignmentExpressionSuffix
    : '.' assignmentExpression
    | ArrayIndex
    | ('()' | '(' expression (',' expression)* ')' )
    ;

methodCall
    : Identifier ('()' | '(' expression (',' expression)* ')' )
    ;

variableName
    : Identifier (variableSuffix)*
    ;

variableSuffix
    : ArrayIndex
    | '.' variableName
    ;

arrayLiteral
    : '[' expression (',' expression)* ']'
    ;

objectLiteral
    : '{' (Identifier '=' expression (',' Identifier '=' expression)*)? '}'
    ;

keyValue
    : Identifier '=' StringLiteral
    ;

StringLiteral
    :  '"' (~('\\'|'"'))* '"'
    ;

 ArrayIndex
    : '[' [1-9] [0-9]* ']'
    | '[' StringLiteral ']'
    ;

Identifier
    : [a-zA-Z0-9]+
    ;

WS
    : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip 
    ;

COMMENT 
    : '/*' .*? '*/'  -> skip
    ;
```

Test.cfc (testing code file)

```
component something = "foo" another = "more" persistent = "true" datasource = "#application.env.dsn#" {
    var method = something.foo.test1;
    testing = something.foo[10];
    testingagain = something.foo["this is a test"];
    nuts["testing"]++;
    blah.test().test3["test"]();

    var math = 1 + 2 - blah.test().test4["test"];

    var test = something;
    var testing = somethingelse;
    var testing = { 
        test = more, 
        mystuff = { 
            interior = test 
        },
        third = "third key"
    };
    other = "Idunno homie";
    methodCall(interiorMethod());

    public function bar() {
        var new = "somebody i used to know";
        something = [1, 2, 3];
    }

    function nuts(required string test1 = "first", string test = "second", test3 = "third") {

    }

    private boolean function baz() {
        var this = "something else";
    }
}
```

Comment: Btw, instead of `'()'`, you probably want to do: `'(' ')'` since the first will not match parenthesis with spaces in between them.

Comment: In case you're not aware, Railo 4 has a more general scope checking tool as part of its debugging options ... doesn't entirely make varscoper redundant, but it does overlap in the problem it solves.

Comment: Also, there's a more complete/general ANTLR parser available - have a look at the stuff [denstar has done](https://github.com/denuno) - might provide some shortcuts.

Comment: @BartKiers if I use `'(' ')'` on the argumentsDefinition rule I get an error that says no viable alternative at input `'()'`. Try it using antlr4 and the files I have provided.

Comment: @Nucleon, ah, okay, that means your grammar isn't correct because it would not parse input like `... function baz( ) { ...` properly.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I wouldn't walk this manually if I were you. After generating a lexer and parser, ANTLR would also have generated a file called `CfscriptBaseListener`  that has empty methods for all of your parser rules. You can let ANTLR walk your tree and attach a custom tree-listener in which you override only those methods/rules you're interested in.

In your case, you probably want to be notified whenever a new function is created (to create a new scope) and you'll probably be interested in variable assignments (`variableStatement` and `nonVarVariableStatement`). Your listener, let's call is `VarListener` will keep track of all scopes as ANTLR walks the tree.

I did change 1 rule slightly (I added `objectLiteralEntry`):

```
objectLiteral
    : '{' (objectLiteralEntry (',' objectLiteralEntry)*)? '}'
    ;

objectLiteralEntry
    : Identifier '=' expression
    ;
```

which makes life easier in the following demo:

### VarListener.java

```java
public class VarListener extends CfscriptBaseListener {

    private Stack<Scope> scopes;

    public VarListener() {
        scopes = new Stack<Scope>();
        scopes.push(new Scope(null));
    } 

    @Override
    public void enterVariableStatement(CfscriptParser.VariableStatementContext ctx) {
        String varName = ctx.variableName().getText();
        Scope scope = scopes.peek();
        scope.add(varName);
    }

    @Override
    public void enterNonVarVariableStatement(CfscriptParser.NonVarVariableStatementContext ctx) {
        String varName = ctx.variableName().getText();
        checkVarName(varName);
    }

    @Override
    public void enterObjectLiteralEntry(CfscriptParser.ObjectLiteralEntryContext ctx) {
        String varName = ctx.Identifier().getText();
        checkVarName(varName);
    }

    @Override
    public void enterFunctionDeclaration(CfscriptParser.FunctionDeclarationContext ctx) {
        scopes.push(new Scope(scopes.peek()));
    }

    @Override
    public void exitFunctionDeclaration(CfscriptParser.FunctionDeclarationContext ctx) {
        scopes.pop();        
    }

    private void checkVarName(String varName) {
        Scope scope = scopes.peek();
        if(scope.inScope(varName)) {
            System.out.println("OK   : " + varName);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Oops : " + varName);
        }
    }
}
```

A `Scope` object could be as simple as:

### Scope.java

```java
class Scope extends HashSet<String> {

    final Scope parent;

    public Scope(Scope parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    boolean inScope(String varName) {
        if(super.contains(varName)) {
            return true;
        }
        return parent == null ? false : parent.inScope(varName);
    }
}
```

Now, to test this all, here's a small main class:

### Main.java

```java
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        CfscriptLexer lexer = new CfscriptLexer(new ANTLRFileStream("Test.cfc"));
        CfscriptParser parser = new CfscriptParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
        ParseTree tree = parser.component();
        ParseTreeWalker.DEFAULT.walk(new VarListener(), tree);
    }
}
```

If you run this `Main` class, the following will be printed:

```
Oops : testing
Oops : testingagain
OK   : test
Oops : mystuff
Oops : interior
Oops : third
Oops : other
Oops : something
```

Without a doubt, this is not exactly what you want and I probably goofed up some scoping rules of Coldfusion. But I think this will give you some insight in how to solve your problem properly. I think the code is pretty self explanatory, but if this is not the case, don't hesitate to ask for clarification.

HTH

Comment: This is an incredibly thorough answer but is a lot to digest. I'll be back in a few days =p.

Comment: No problem @Nucleon. Again: feel free to ask for clarification if I passed over certain aspects too quickly.

Comment: Hint: `ParseTreeWalker.DEFAULT.walk(...)`

Comment: This method works beautifully. I made some tweaks to it but your example was invaluable. You can view the files I derived from this at the github at https://github.com/owenallenaz/CfscriptVarscoper/tree/master/java. Thanks again.

Comment: @BartKiers Hey there. I'm a beginner to ANTLR as well. I'm trying to use something like your main code to walk my parsetree, but my generated gardenParser object does not have a component() class. Do you have any idea why this might be?

Comment: @ZachH, the parser has a `component` method because the grammar has a `component` rule. Your grammar probably does not have such a rule.

Comment: Thaat would be why. I was wondering why my resulting parsers had none of the functions available in tutorials. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not using ANTLR but this answer provided insight that's been invaluable in writing methods for my own custom parser. Thanks!

Comment: For me this doesn't work well because left-recursive rules do weird stuff... What can I do for this?

Comment: Best you create a question of your own @paul

Comment: @BartKiers I have already found out how, figured that it doesn't work well with the listener but the visitor did what I needed.