# ANTLR chaining 1 to 1 grammar rules together to solve conditionals

Tags: conditional-statements, antlr4

If you look at the ObjectiveC antlr v3 grammars (http://www.antlr3.org/grammar/1212699960054/ObjectiveC2ansi.g), and many of the other popular grammars out there they do a similar structure to this for solving conditionals

```
conditional_expression : logical_or_expression 
  ('?' logical_or_expression ':' logical_or_expression)? ;

constant_expression : conditional_expression ;

logical_or_expression : logical_and_expression 
  ('||' logical_and_expression)* ;

logical_and_expression : inclusive_or_expression 
  ('&&' inclusive_or_expression)* ;

inclusive_or_expression : exclusive_or_expression 
  ('|' exclusive_or_expression)* ;

exclusive_or_expression : and_expression ('^' and_expression)* ;

and_expression : equality_expression ('&' equality_expression)* ;

equality_expression : relational_expression 
  (('!=' | '==') relational_expression)* ;

relational_expression : shift_expression
 (('<' | '>' | '<=' | '>=') shift_expression)* ;

shift_expression : additive_expression (('<<' | '>>') additive_expression)* ;

additive_expression : multiplicative_expression
  (('+' | '-') multiplicative_expression)* ;

multiplicative_expression : cast_expression 
  (('*' | '/' | '%') cast_expression)* ;

cast_expression : '(' type_name ')' cast_expression | unary_expression ;

unary_expression 
  : postfix_expression
  | '++' unary_expression
  | '--' unary_expression
  | unary_operator cast_expression
  | 'sizeof' ('(' type_name ')' | unary_expression) ;

unary_operator : '&' | '*' | '-' | '~' | '!' ;
```

If you read it you'll notice they do this very long 1 to 1 chain of conditionals from `conditional_expression` to `logical_or_expression` to `logical_and_expression` to `inclusive_or_expression` to `exclusive_or_expression`.

Now, I am quite naive when it comes to ANTLR but this strikes me as an odd way to parse conditionals. It seems very complicated for the definition of a logical_or_expression to twist through every single other conditional expression type. Afterall, what does the definition of a logical `OR` have to do with a left bitwise shift?

Is there perhaps a better way, or is there a specific reason this method is required?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As already mentioned, the "chain" is needed to properly handle operator precedence. Without it, input like `1+2*3` would be parsed as:

```
     *
    / \
   +   3
  / \
 1   2
```

instead of:

```
  +
 / \
1   *
   / \
  2   3
```

Since ANTLR 4 supports direct left recursive rules:

```
foo
 : foo '?' foo
 | TOKEN
 ;
```

so not indirect left recursive rules:

```
foo
 : bar
 | TOKEN
 ;

bar
 : foo '?' foo
 ;
```

You can rewrite these rules as follows:

```
expression
 : '-' expression
 | '(' type_name ')' expression
 | expression ('*' | '/' | '%') expression
 | expression ('+' | '-') expression
 | expression ('<<' | '>>') expression
 | expression ('<' | '>' | '<=' | '>=') expression
 | expression ('!=' | '==') expression
 | expression '&' expression
 | expression '^' expression
 | expression '|' expression
 | expression '&&' expression
 | expression '||' expression
 | expression '?' expression ':' expression
 | IDENTIFIER
 | NUMBER
 ;
```

If the parser now stumbles upon an `expression`, it will first look for `('*' | '/' | '%')`, and if that's not there, it will look for `('+' | '-')`, etc. In other words, the alternatives placed first in the rule will get precedence over alternatives placed lower in the rule.

Now I know from your earlier question, [Once grammar is complete, what's the best way to walk an ANTLR v4 tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15050137/once-grammar-is-complete-whats-the-best-way-to-walk-an-antlr-v4-tree), that you're using a listener to "walk" the tree. If you create an `expression` rule as I just showed, you'd need to do a lot of manual inspections in your `enterExpression(...)` and `exitExpression(...)` methods to find out which of the alternatives matched an `expression`. This is where "labels" come in handy. You simply label each alternative in your `expression` rule:

```
expression
 : '-' expression                                  #unaryExpr
 | '(' type_name ')' expression                    #castExpr
 | expression ('*' | '/' | '%') expression         #multExpr
 | expression ('+' | '-') expression               #addExpr
 | expression ('<<' | '>>') expression             #...
 | expression ('<' | '>' | '<=' | '>=') expression 
 | expression ('!=' | '==') expression
 | expression '&' expression
 | expression '^' expression
 | expression '|' expression
 | expression '&&' expression
 | expression '||' expression
 | expression '?' expression ':' expression
 | IDENTIFIER
 | NUMBER
 ;
```

(note that when you label one, you *must* label them all!)

And then the base listener class will have `enter`- and `exit` method for all alternatives:

```
public void enterUnaryExpr(...)
public void exitUnaryExpr(...)

public void enterCastExpr(...)
public void exitCastExpr(...)

public void enterMultExpr(...)
public void exitMultExpr(...)

...
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good reason for doing it this way: operator precedence. Taking your example of the logical OR and left bitwise shift, think about something like

```
if (a << b || c)
```

Objective-C precedence rules say that the '<<' has precedence, so the correct way to evaluate this is

```
(a << b) || c
```

The parser rules manage this by using the chain you mention, because the rule for '||' is higher up in the chain, the parse correctly gives a << b as a subexpression for the || operator.

There is no better way in Antl3, however in Antlr4, there is, as Antlr4 allows directly left recursive rules. I highly recommend the "Definitive Antlr4 reference" as it has a very good explanation of this issue.