# the following sets of rules are mutually left-recursive

Tags: antlr4

The sumScalarOperator gives me this error, it seems that antlr see it like a possible infinite recursion loop. How can i avoid it?

```
sumScalarOperator: function SUM_TOKEN function;

function :
         | INTEGER_TOKEN
         | NUMERIC_TOKEN
         | sumScalarOperator
         | ID;

ID : [A-Za-z_-] [a-zA-Z0-9_-]*;
INTEGER_TOKEN: [0-9]+;
NUMERIC_TOKEN: [0-9]+'.'[0-9]+ ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ANTLR4 can't cope with mutually left-recursive rules, but it can rewrite single left-recursive rules automatically to eliminate the left-recursion, so you can just feed it with something like:

```
function : function SUM_TOKEN function  # sumScalarOperator
         | INTEGER_TOKEN                # value
         | NUMERIC_TOKEN                # value
         | ID                           # value
         ;
```

Replace the `value` label with anything you need.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly. I link another discussion of relevant importance for the argument that explain the recursion and find possible implementation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15106240/antlr-chaining-1-to-1-grammar-rules-together-to-solve-conditionals