# antlr4: Ignore superflous tokens when creating ParseTrees

Tags: antlr4

I am developing a compiler for the real-time language PEARL with ANTLR4.

With ANTLR4 my ParseTree is populated with superflous tokens like e.g. semicolons for ending a 
grammatical unit.

Is there a way to tell ANTLR to ignore these kinds of token?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way to tell ANTLR to ignore these kind of tokens?

No, but using ANTLR4's built-in listener/visitor, there's no need to remove these tokens.

See: ["skip" changes parser behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129658/skip-changes-parser-behavior)

Comment: Yes, with the current Visitor and Listener methods, doing nothing with the token is literally the same as ignoring it.