# ANTLR 4 taking decisions from a parse tree

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I need to take some decisions depending on the structure and information in a parse tree, this is an example of the trees I am generating now:

[image: Parse Tree]

The decisions for generating code will depend on the operator(";","AND","OR","XOR") between two workflows, for instance the code I need to generate from this tree is

```
mustPrecede(T6,T4) AND mustPrecede(T6,T1) 
AND  mustPrecede(T4,T5) AND  mustPrecede(T1,T5)
```

For this I need to find out that the operator between T6 and (T4 AND T1) is ";" (sequential composition operator) for taking a decision and then I need to find out that between T4 and T1 the operator is "AND" and then I need to get the T4 and T1 to make a relation with T5. My question is how can I encode this in a parser?.

This is my grammar definition

```
grammar Hello;      

execution: workflow EOF;

workflow : Task 
         | workflow OPERATOR workflow 
         |'(' workflow (OPERATOR workflow)+ ')' 
         ;

Task : 'T' ('0'..'9')+ 
     | 'WF' ('0'..'9')+
     ;

OPERATOR: 'AND' 
        | 'OR'  
        | 'XOR' 
        | ';' 
        ;

WS  :   [ \t\n\r]+ -> channel(HIDDEN) ;
```

Answer (score 4):

You created one token, `OPERATOR`, which represents all of your operators. This makes it very difficult to distinguish between the different operators. An easier set of rules would be the following:

```
operator
  : AND
  | OR
  | XOR
  | SEMI
  ;

AND : 'AND';
OR  : 'OR';
XOR : 'XOR;
SEMI : ';';
```

You would also replace references to `OPERATOR` with references to `operator`. Then, in your implementation of a listener or visitor, you could create methods like the following (using an example from a listener).

```
@Override
public void enterWorkflow(WorkflowContext ctx) {
  List<? extends OperatorContext> operatorContexts = ctx.operator();
  if (operatorContexts.isEmpty()) {
    // handle just a Task
  } else {
    for (OperatorContext operatorContext : ctx.operator()) {
      switch (operatorContext.getStart().getType()) {
      case HelloLexer.AND:
        // handle 'AND'
        break;
      case HelloLexer.OR:
        // handle 'OR'
        break;
      case HelloLexer.XOR:
        // handle 'XOR'
        break;
      case HelloLexer.SEMI:
        // handle ';'
        break;
      default:
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unrecognized operator.");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this makes sense for making a difference between the operators thanks, perhaps my problem (question) was more about how to deal with the levels in the tree, what I mean with this  is how to navigate it. From your answer I can infer that the implementation of a visitor is the way , can you suggested me where can I find more information in relation to this? thanks a lot.

Comment: See related question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15050137/once-grammar-is-complete-whats-the-best-way-to-walk-an-antlr-v4-tree?rq=1